# Deleting the contents of cells if a checkbox is clicked when a command button is pressed

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, selection

I am building an order configuration spreadsheet. The various product categories have options which are incompatible, so I created some checkboxes in column A. I want to make a control button select the contents of each row from column H:L that has a selected checkbox and delete it and then unselect the checkbox. I don't really know how to write such code. Your help is really appreciated.

```
Sub EliminateCheckBoxes() 
    Dim CB As CheckBox, n As Long, x As Long 
    n = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Count 
    For x = n To 1 Step -1 
        Set CB = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(x) 
        If CB.Name <> "Check Box 1" Then 
    Next x 
End Sub
```

Comment: I added some VBA code that deletes my checkboxes I want it instead to delete the contents of the row containing the checkbox from H:L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a property of the checkbox that links to your relevant row. Either (if linked) use .LinkedCell (string then get the range object) or else if positioned on the relevant row then .TopLeftCell (range)

E.g.:

```
'Using LinkedCell
Range(cb.LinkedCell).EntireRow.Range("H1:L1").Delete

'or using TopLeftCell
cb.TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Range("H1:L1").Delete

cb.Value = -4146 'uncheck the checkbox
```

Example of your code with the above and an added check for whether the checkbox is checked:

```
Sub EliminateCheckBoxes() 
    Dim CB As CheckBox, n As Long, x As Long 
    n = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Count 
    For x = n To 1 Step -1 
        Set CB = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(x)
        If CB.Name <> "Check Box 1" Then 'are you intentionally excluding Check Box 1?
            If CB.Value = 1 then
                CB.TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Range("H1:L1").ClearContents
                CB.Value = -4146 'uncheck the checkbox
            End If
        End If
    Next x 
End Sub
```

Comment: I swapped in ClearContents instead of Delete and that worked. However, this clears the contents of all the H:L range for every cell with a checkbox whether or not it was checked. I want to only clear the contents of that H:L range though if the checkbox in that row was already selected. Tried this... didn't work.  If CB.Name <> "Check Box 14" And CB.Value = True Then Range(CB.LinkedCell).EntireRow.Range("G1:L1").ClearContents.

Comment: @RichardPullman yep, you  didn't test for whether it is checked. To test that use the Value property. If it is checked then it is 1, it it is not check then it is -4146 (for some reason..!). Check my amended answer with an example.

Comment: CB.Value=1 instead of True solves problem. :-) Thanks, I feel like I'm learning and you guys helped me out tremendously.

Comment: @RichardPullman Us too. I haven't used the Worksheet embedded checkboxes before but your question gave an excuse to jump in to the object browser, locals and immediates windows, play around and have a look ;)